# How to make a web user control public

Tags: asp.net

My page contains several web user controls. Those controls contains other child controls, and those contains more child controls and so on. From my page, I want to be able to access those controls, like I do with other public classes: `uc1.uc1_child1.uc1_child1_child1.Update();`

(I do know about the FindControl method, and thats what Im currently using. It's however not type safe, and I need to lookup the names of the controls all the time to be on safe side. Much more time consuming than intellisense)

Comment: You could make `Property` type `Control` for each control u want to access with `get` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a public property on your usercontrol for each of the usercontrols it contains, that should work.

eg

```
 public SpecificUserControlType ContainedUserControl
 {
      get
      {
          return this.uc1_child;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: I'm able to see the property, but I cant access any methods or child controls of the child. Reference problem parhaps?

Comment: You need to make them public in the child too to be able to see them.

Comment: It started to work when I added a reference to all child controls at the Page.